# Draggable object doesn't recognize target Javascript Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm new to Javascript, but I customized a code from an array of number to an array of letters in which I want to recognize the target in order to complete the game.

The error in the code is that its drops to any of the targets, that means that it doesn't recognize the respectively target.

[The original code](http://jsfiddle.net/Nellymar/vnynj/)
and the [code that I customized](http://jsfiddle.net/Nellymar/8ngVj/).

```
var correctCards = 0;
$(init);

function init() {
    // Hide the success message
    $('#successMessage').hide();
    $('#successMessage').css({
        left: '580px',
        top: '250px',
        width: 0,
        height: 0
    });

    // Reset the game
    correctCards = 0;
    $('#vocalPile').html('');
    $('#vocalSlots').html('');

    // Create the pile of shuffled cards
    var vocales = ["a", 'e','i' , 'o', 'u'];
    vocales.sort( function() { return Math.random() - .5 } );

    for ( var i=0; i<5; i++ ) {
        $('<div>' + vocales[i] + '</div>')
          .data('vocal', vocales[i])
          .attr('id', 'vocal'+vocales[i])
          .appendTo('#vocalPile')
          .draggable({
              containment: '#content',
              stack: '#vocalPile div',
              cursor: 'move',
              revert: true
          });
    }

    // Create the card slots
    var words = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'];
    for (var i = 1; i <= 5; i++ ) {
        $('<div>' + words[i-1] + '</div>')
          .data('vocal', i)
          .appendTo('#vocalSlots')
          .droppable({
              accept: '#vocalPile div',
              hoverClass: 'hovered',
              drop: handleCardDrop
          });
    }

}

function handleCardDrop( event, ui ) {
    var slotVocal = $(this).data('vocales');
    var cardVocal = ui.draggable.data('vocales');

    // If the card was dropped to the correct slot,
    // change the card colour, position it directly
    // on top of the slot, and prevent it being dragged
    // again

    if ( slotVocal == cardVocal ) {
        ui.draggable.addClass('correct');
        ui.draggable.draggable('disable');
        $(this).droppable('disable');
        ui.draggable.position({ of: $(this), my: 'left top', at: 'left top' });
        ui.draggable.draggable('option', 'revert', false);
        correctCards++;
    } 

    // If all the cards have been placed correctly then display a message
    // and reset the cards for another go

    if (correctCards == 5) {
        $('#successMessage').show();
        $('#successMessage').animate( {
            left: '380px',
            top: '200px',
            width: '400px',
            height: '100px',
            opacity: 1
        });
    }
}
```

I think that there's an error in the parameters that is passing through the functions. But I dont know how to change them in the if ==.

Thanks :)

PS. Is an array of vowels not number the one that I want to implement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an error in

in create card slots:

```
$('<div>' + words[i-1] + '</div>')
.data( 'vocal',words[i-1])...
```

use **words** array

in **handleCardDrop** function fix data attribute to **vocal** not **vocales** as in your fiddle

```
function handleCardDrop( event, ui ) {
  var slotVocal = $(this).data( 'vocal' );
  var cardVocal = ui.draggable.data( 'vocal' );
```

working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/waldekciara/CpccE/1/)